# Integrating with respect to a shifting of measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha > 0$. My question is about the comparison between:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(\alpha x) \quad \text{ and } \quad  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(x).
$$
Does exist properties about the scaling measures?

Actually I am searching for a comparison result between the two following quantities
$$ 
\inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(\alpha x) \quad \text{ and } \quad \inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(x),
$$
where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a convex set of measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks,

S

Comment: By a change of variables you get $\int f(x) d\mu(\alpha x) = \int f(x/\alpha) d\mu(x)$. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I am searching for a comparison result between the two following quantities
$$ 
\inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(\alpha x) \quad \text{ and } \quad \inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) d\mu(x),
$$
where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a convex set of measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.